# schema evolution in avro

Tags: schema, avro

Why is decoding using a backwards compatible schema not supported in Avro?

Is my understanding around Avro schema evolution correct? -

While decoding, the reader must know about the schema with which the writer encoded some data. You can't expect the reader to be able to use a latest schema which evolved in backwards-compatible way, to decode data which is being encoded by the reader using some earlier schema version.

Avro needs schema registries to support evolution decoding. The reader and writer both have access to such a registry, and "register" new schema versions while also maintaining a local cache. The encoding also adds a "schema version identifier", which is used on the reader side to figure out the schema version, and fetch it from cache/schema registry.

However, this means that the read can happen off the older schema version. If the evolved schema had a field deleted OR a field added with default value (since evolution is backwards compatible), this modification has to be done and maintained separately from the decoding process.

Answer (score 0):

> can't expect the reader to be able to use a latest schema which evolved in backwards-compatible way, to decode data which is being encoded by the reader using some earlier schema version.

I assume you meant *encoded by the writer*, here? As long as you can have the reader use some lookup mechanism to get the "latest" (in terms of time), then that's possible.

Otherwise, reader can define whatever subset of fields it wants to project out of the data, much like a SQL query. Fields are matched by name, not by 'schema version" (which isn't a term in the Avro spec).

> Avro needs schema registries to support evolution decoding

It does not. Seems like you may be conflating Confluent's documented pattern of using Avro with the actual Avro spec, which makes no reference to a Registry.

The Avro spec documents how "evolution" (they call it resolution) works [between Avro schemas](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.11.1/specification/#schema-resolution).

> the read can happen off the older schema version

Yes. The reader can also define its own, new, but still compatible, version as mentioned above.